# readUTF() returns error after writeObject()

Tags: java, sockets

I'm setting up a new server-client system. Here from the client, an object will be sent to the server. And after receiving the object the server will send a string to the client.

Here the server reads the object successfully. But when the clients want to read the string sent by the server it throws EOFException.

client-side

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, EOFException {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1254)) {

        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream s1In;
        DataInputStream dis;
        try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream)) {
            s1In = socket.getInputStream();
            dis = new DataInputStream(s1In);
            Frame frame = new Frame();
            frame.setData("test");
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(frame);

        String st = "";
        while(dis.available() >0){
            st = dis.readUTF();
        }
        System.out.println(st);
        }
        dis.close();
        s1In.close();
    }
}
```

server-side

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(1254);
    Socket socket = s.accept(); 
    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);


    //input stream
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame = (Frame) objectInputStream.readObject();
    String data = frame.getData();
    System.out.println(data);
    // Send a string!
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream (outputStream);
    dos.writeUTF("Received");
    dos.close();
    objectOutputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
    objectInputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

error at client side

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at computernetworklab.Client.main(Client.java:38)
/home/shahad/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java 
returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```